# Get the only the last row in a sequence. SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:

```
ID    Seq    Prod
-----------------
1     001     1
2     002     1
3     001     2
4     002     2
5     003     2
```

I want to make a query that only gets the last "Seq" of each product, so the expected output will be something like this:

```
ID    Seq    Prod
-----------------
2     002     1
5     003     2
```

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple way is a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.seq = (select max(t2.seq) from t t2 where t2.prod = t.prod);
```

For performance, you want an index on `(prod, seq)`.

The above often has the best performance.  But another way to write the query is to use window fucntions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by prod order by seq desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 3):

Yet another option is using `WITH TIES`

```
Select top 1 * with ties
 From  YourTable
 Order By row_number() over (partition by prod order by seq desc)
```

**Full Disclosure:**

Gordon's answer is a nudge more performant (+1), but `WITH TIES` does not generate an extra column.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a sub-query that finds the maximum `ID` by `Prod`.  In the following example, replace 'myTable' with your table name:

```
SELECT  t.*
  FROM  myTable t
    INNER JOIN (
                SELECT  MAX(ID) AS ID,
                        Prod
                  FROM  myTable
                  GROUP BY Prod
                ) a ON a.ID = t.ID
```

Output:

```
ID  Seq Prod
2   002 1
5   003 2
```

Here is a quick, working [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e2d7d/1).

Answer (score 0):

You can write a correlated subquery as:

```
select T.ID,T.Seq,T.Prod 
from @T1 T 
where T.ID = (select max(T_Inner.ID)
             from @T1 T_Inner
             where T_Inner.Prod = T.Prod 
             group by T_Inner.Prod 
            )
```